# How to code in app secrets and tokens for Facebook authentication in Google Scripts without having the credentials in the script?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script, facebook-access-token

I have a script that can obtain successfully from the Facebook oAuth API:

```
function getToken() {
  var appId = "XXXXXX"; 
  var clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+appId+"&client_secret="+clientSecret+"&grant_type=client_credentials";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var queryResult = response.getContentText(); 
  var token = queryResult.slice(13);
  return(token);
}
```

The question is, that I prefer not to have my appId and clientSecret in the body of my script so is there a way where I can code this in without having my credentials in plain text?

Comment: The app access token should never be used in client-side code. If you need to use the app access token, then you need to do it server-side. If you can use a user access token instead, then let users login first, and use their token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Manually enter the keys and secret into the script editor as a "Script Property" (File > Project properties > Script properties) and then access them in the code using the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service).

For example you could manually add:

```
property:APP_ID, value:'XXXXXXXX'
```

Then access it in the code with

```
var appId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('APP_ID')
```

This technique works if you wanted to share the script on somewhere like Github, or if you only gave out view-access to the script in which case the script properties aren't visible (you should not be able to see the SPs in [this script](https://script.google.com/d/1voZgtn_o7eJqU32bZbZSSF1iHJ7DEpHRu_LMpQETIBZ4mejWfIHEOk6A/edit?usp=sharing&pli=1)). If you give edit access to others they'll be able to see the SPs, but then you could use User Properties.

Comment: Thanks! Can the user then go to the project properties-> script properties to see it?

Comment: Updated my answer to add use cases.

Answer (score -5):

For that you need to install latest facebook SDK which uses Namespace and protected methods to get facebook data using graph api. Below is an example I worked on :

```
require_once ROOT . '/vendor/Facebook/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
class FacebookComponent extends Component
{
    public $app_id;
    public $app_secret;
    public $default_graph_version;

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->app_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $this->app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $this->default_graph_version = "v2.5"; // For Offerz-develop app

    }
    public function getFacebookConn(){
    $app_id = $this->app_id;
    $app_secret = $this->app_secret;
    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => $app_id,
        'app_secret' => $app_secret,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);
    return $fb;

    }
    }
```

Comment: you still hardcoded the secrets plus used the wrong language.